# Download all .mp4 files present in a Dropbox folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, dropbox, mp4

Downloading a file from [Dropbox using the API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial) it's straightforward once having the Access Token.

Then, using the method [sharing_get_shared_link_file](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.sharing_get_shared_link_file) one can simply run

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("ACCESS_TOKEN")
#dbx.users_get_current_account()
with open("test1.mp4", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kowz06jo7i3xyv2/you_saved_me.mp4?dl=0")
    f.write(res.content)
```

As you can see in the URL, **/s/** means that we're dealing with one file.

Thing is, sometimes it's not one file but a folder where the file resides and so the link will include **/sh/** instead.

How could I download all the .mp4 files present in a specific folder one by one ([without .zip](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download_zip))?

For reference, created a folder with three .mp4 files in it - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r85vzhq0xxa146s/AAASRlyR-C9ITAd0Cww0Sr9Za?dl=0

[image: Dropbox folder with multiple .mp4 files in it]

Comment: The documentation you linked shows you how to list all the files in a directory.

Comment: See also https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download_zip and https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder

Comment: Great, thank you @PeterWood. So we'd need to know the name of the file or download all as .zip?

Comment: I mean, there's no way to just download all .mp4 present in there one by one (no .zip) without caring about their names?

Comment: I don’t know, I’ve never used Dropbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a shared link to a folder containing files, instead of just a shared link to a specific file, you can use [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder) and [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue) to list the contents of that folder. You can do so by passing in the URL in the `shared_link` parameter for [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder).

The result will contain information about the contents, such as the [`name`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.Metadata.name) of each one.

You can then use that to build the `path` to pass to `sharing_get_shared_link_file` to download each desired file.

That would look something like this, based on your existing code and URL:

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("ACCESS_TOKEN")

shared_link = dropbox.files.SharedLink(url="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r85vzhq0xxa146s/AAASRlyR-C9ITAd0Cww0Sr9Za?dl=0")

listing = dbx.files_list_folder(path="", shared_link=shared_link)
# todo: add implementation for files_list_folder_continue

for entry in listing.entries:
    if entry.name.endswith(".mp4"):
        with open(entry.name, "wb") as f:
            # note: this simple implementation only works for files in the root of the folder
            metadata, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=shared_link.url, path="/" + entry.name)
            f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: Thank you Greg, exactly that... Can only upvote tomorrow due to upvote limit.